# Table name as variable in sql server

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2017, sp-executesql

I am performing stored procedures the input option is as follows:

```
 Declare @table varchar (20)
 Set @query = 'Select * from' + @table + 'Where id = 1'
 Exec sp_executesql @query
```

The question is can it be done in some other way without the SQL being handled as varchar?

I was thinking along the lines of something similar to the following:

```
Declare @varchar varchar(20)
Set @tabla = 'MyTabla'
SELECT * FROM @table
```

Comment: No, you cannot refer to a table dynamically without using... dynamic SQL. Also, please be much safer than that ... see [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server-part-1/) and [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server-part-2/).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Only I just wanted to know if there is another way to do it

Comment: This is sort of a weird thing to do anyway. The tables in your database probably have different schemas (different columns), so a `select * from Table1` would return a different set of columns than a `select * from Table2`. So, when your client code runs, you probably need to handle those results differently (unless you're just loading into a dynamic datagridview, or generating an HTML table based on the output schema, or some other "direct from DB to dynamic GUI" sort of thing).

Comment: Side notes: you should store object names in `sysname` variables (synonym for `nvarchar(128)` and you should escape them correctly with the `quotename` function